# Как сделать фиксированный (плавающий) элемент?

Tags: android, xml

Как сделать без всяких сторонних библиотек через XML фиксированную позицию элемента, например нижнее меню. (Без android.support.design)

Comment: а в чем проблема взять constraint layout и привязать элемент к нижней части экрана?

Comment: Хм, попробую сделать так :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант #1

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Вариант #2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Вариант #3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]